# HTML Javascript phone number verify

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
 <form id="loginform" onsubmit="return checkinput()" method="post" action="estcok.php">
    Name:<input type="text" name="acuser" id="login_name" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\a-\z\A-\Z_]/g,'')" onkeydown="fncKeyStop(event)" onpaste="return false" oncontextmenu="return false">
    <P>NAME
    <p>Phone number:<input type="text" name="acpass" id="login_pass">
    <p>Phone number
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

script

```
function checkinput() {
                var okname = document.getElementById("login_name");
                if ( okname.value.length < 3 || okname.value.length > 20 ) {
                        window.alert ( "Name<3 >20" );
                        document.getElementById("login_name").focus();
                        return false;
                }
                        var ce= /^09[0-9]{8}$/;
                        var pp=ce.exec((document.getElementById("login_pass").value);
                        
             if (pp) 
                { 
                    alert("no"); 
                    document.getElementById("login_passe").focus(); 
                    return false;           
                }
}
```

I cannot verify login_passe....It is not work...
I need verify 10 number and 09XXXXXXXXXX.
thank you.

Comment: Please go inform yourself what the `exec` method actually returns. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Answer (score 0):

You should change method to `test` and need use `!pp` for your condition as

```
var ce= /^09[0-9]{8}$/;
var pp=ce.test(document.getElementById("login_pass").value);
                        
if (!pp) 
{ 
    alert("no"); 
    document.getElementById("login_passe").focus(); 
    return false;           
}
```

```js
function checkinput() {
                var okname = document.getElementById("login_name");
                if ( okname.value.length < 3 || okname.value.length > 20 ) {
                        window.alert ( "Name<3 >20" );
                        document.getElementById("login_name").focus();
                        return false;
                }
                        var ce= /^09[0-9]{8}$/;
                        var pp=ce.test(document.getElementById("login_pass").value);
                        
             if (!pp) 
                { 
                    alert("no"); 
                    document.getElementById("login_passe").focus(); 
                    return false;           
                }
}
```

```html
 <form id="loginform" onsubmit="return checkinput()" method="post" action="estcok.php">
    Name:<input type="text" name="acuser" id="login_name" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\a-\z\A-\Z_]/g,'')" onkeydown="fncKeyStop(event)" onpaste="return false" oncontextmenu="return false">
    <P>NAME
    <p>Phone number:<input type="text" name="acpass" id="login_pass">
    <p>Phone number
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```